# Как исправить ошибку при создании mesh в WebGL?

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

На WebGL я реализовал сферу покрытую текстуркой планеты земли.

Решил написать загрузчик ресурсов на промисах и как всё загрузиться начинать уже основной цикл отрисовки.

Но в итоге я вижу вот это :(

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как пофиксить данную ошибку или как бы написали вы? :)

**Использую three.js**

Вот js код:

```
;(function(root,doc){


    let _earth = function(material){

        let geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(200,30,30);

        return new THREE.Mesh(geometry,material);// СОБСТВЕННО ТУТ ОШИБКА ВЫЛЕТАЕТ, а все предупреждения ещё во время загрузки.

    };

    /*

        Load all resources

    */

    const resourceLoader = {};

    resourceLoader.load = function(_res){//массив ресурсов

        let _loadRes = function(resource){// load only resource

            let _resTypes = {
                texture:function(res,url){// response, url
                    let loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

                    loader.load(url, function(texture){
                        return res(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial(texture));
                    });
                },
                // audio,objects, images
            };

            return new Promise(function(res, rej){
                _resTypes[resource.type](res,resource.url);
            });

        }

        let _resources = map(_res,_loadRes);

        return Promise.all(_resources);// load all resources

    }


    const _init = function(){

        /*

            Windows width and height for WebGL perspective

        */

        const WINDOW_WIDTH  = root.innerWidth,
                    WINDOW_HEIGHT = root.innerHeight;

        /*

            Canvas DOM element for render frames WebGL

        */

        const CANVAS = doc.getElementById('scene');


        /*

            Set canvas width and height

        */

        CANVAS.setAttribute('width',WINDOW_WIDTH);
        CANVAS.setAttribute('height',WINDOW_HEIGHT);

        /*

            Resources

        */

        const RESOURCES = [
            {type:'texture', url:'textures/earth.jpg'},
        ];

        /*

            Renderer WebGL

        */

        const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas:CANVAS});

        renderer.setClearColor(0x000000);


        /*

            Scena

        */

        const scene = new THREE.Scene();

        /*

        Camera

        */

        const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45,WINDOW_WIDTH/WINDOW_HEIGHT, 0.1, 5000);

        camera.position.set(0,0,1000);//придвинута на 1000 пикселей

        /*

            Add basic light

        */

        let light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff);

        scene.add(light);

        /*

            Load all resources

        */

        resourceLoader.load(RESOURCES).then(function(res){
            console.log('All resources load!');

            let earth = _earth(res[0]);

            scene.add(earth);

            let loop = function(){
                renderer.render(scene, camera);

                earth.rotation.y += 0.01;

                requestAnimationFrame(loop);
            };

            loop();

        });

    }

    _init();


    /*

        Set geometry random color texture

    */

    function setRandomColorTexture(geometry){

        let material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0xffffff,vertexColors:THREE.FaceColors});

        for(let i = 0; i<geometry.faces.length; i++){
            geometry.faces[i].color.setRGB(Math.random(),Math.random(),Math.random());
        }

    }


    /*

        Array.map polifill

    */

    function map(array,fn) {
        var rv = [];

        for(var i=0, l=array.length; i<l; i++)
            rv.push(fn(array[i]));

        return rv;
    };


})(this,document);
```

На всякий и html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>WebGL</title>
    <style>
        html,body{
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            overflow:hidden;
            height:100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <canvas id="scene"></canvas>

    <!-- Three js  -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/three.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Index -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При вызове `_earth(res[0])`, вместо `res[0]` передавать объект типа `Material` (`MeshBasicMaterial`, например), у которого параметр `map` - текстура, основанная на `res[0].url`

В Three.js так же есть `LoadingManager`, который как раз позволяет сначала загрузить все ресурсы, а потом вызывать основной цикл отрисовки.

```
var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
manager.onLoad = function () {
    loop();
};
```